# npm run dev do not update any CSS or JS changes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, tailwind-css, vite

I work on a local server (development) with apache/laravel/vuejs/tailwindss and vite.js.

I try to run `npm run dev` but It failed with this error message :

```
Vite manifest not found at
```

I fixed this error by running `npm run build`.

Then I run `npm run dev` again, all JS and CSS changes are not being updated, so I m force to run `npm run build` again ? Is there a problem in my config files then ?

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: false, //not working
      },

    build: {
        minify: false // good
      },

    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            hotFile: 'storage/vite.hot', // Customize the "hot" file path
            refresh: false, // desactivate HMR
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

myTest.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss','resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <span class ="text-sky-500 dark:text-sky-400">Laravel</span>

        
    <div class= "text-amber-800">cannot updated CSS here</div>
    <p class="text-lime-400">Ordinary text.</p>


    <div id="app">
  <example-component />

  </div>

    <button>TEST</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

edit : package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch",
        "preview": "vite preview --port 8080"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2"
    }
}
```